# Can't ssh from external network

Tags: ssh, debian, remote-access

My friend and I are trying to get ssh access on his server working from external networks. He is running Debian 7.1. He can access the server from the internal network but every time I try to access his server (of course from an external network), I get the following error.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
MyUser@HisServer.com's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 56 padlen 8 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Permission of `~/.ssh/` is 700 and `~/.ssh/*` is 600. He has

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
```

included in his `sshd_config`.
Port checker says that Port 22/tcp is open. Strangest thing is that we can't find any history of access in the log. `sudo grep ssh /var/log/*` only shows his activity.
Thus, I suspect it's the router's config that's causing the problem, but shouldn't we be able to ssh if the port is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why we couldn't ssh from external networks was because my friend had a "nested LAN".

It turns out that his apartment had its own LAN, so even after he port-forwarded tcp/22 to his server's private IP address (within his home's LAN), external access got stuck at the apartment's LAN.

He could have paid around $30 per port to open ports with numbers larger than 1000, if I remember correctly, but he figured it wasn't worth it, so we basically gave up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your router or DSL modem to port forward port 22 to the IP address of your server on port 22.
A simple test to do to check if it is a connectivity issue is to telnet on port 22:

```
telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 22
```

where the x's represent the external IP address of your router.

Comment: `telnet` shows `Escape character is '^]'. SSH-1.99-OpenSSH_5.2`. Does that mean it's a misconfiguration and not the router's fault?

Comment: Not the router fault. You are connecting OK. Next thing is to try using another computer to connect to the server. By the way, can your friend connect to his server from the external network?

Comment: I tried connecting from my own server and from my phone but no luck. He hasn't had the chance to do that yet.

Comment: My friend also couldn't connect from an external network. I wonder if this has to do with Debian 7.1...

Comment: Well, it does not look like an O.S. problem anymore. Otherwise, your friend would fail to connect within his internal network. Something on the router must be causing the issue. I am researching the issue...

Comment: Could you switch password authentication on, if only temporarily?

Comment: When your friend tried to connect from the external network, did he use the same machine that succeeded in connecting from within his internal network?

Comment: Changing `PasswordAuthentication` to yes didn't change anything. He tried connecting from an external network with the same computer but it didn't work. I actually had the chance to remote-access his internal network, then ssh to the Debian server, and I noticed a few weird things. Even though when I `telnet` from inside the network it says it's using `SSH-2.0 OpenSSH 6.2`, `telnet`ing from outside tells me I'm still using OpenSSH 5.2. Also, the same thing happened when the `ssh` was supposed to be stopped. I can't find an explanation to these...

Comment: Could you please have a look at your router port mapping? I am suspecting something...

Comment: We used to have 21,22,80/tcp forwarded to `192.168.11.10`, which is the server's local IP address. We made access to any port to go to `192.168.11.10` and even set up a DMZ, but still, no luck. This is just my guess but is it possible that we're accessing the ISP's ssh server (which has SSH1.99-OpenSSH 5.2 running) instead of our own server?

Comment: Since you assencially ssh'ing to your router which properly or not so properly port forwards to your server, the ISP does not seem to be the culprit. However,  my suspicion,  that I did not state previously is that you are not hitting your server, somehow. You could confirm by looking at active connections on your server while ssh'ing from the external network.  You could also look at your router log.

Comment: We monitored active connections by `netstat -tanc | grep 22` and found out there is no connection from the client. My friend will try messing around with the router's settings (especially the ones regarding firewall) and hopefully get it to work.

Comment: It looks like you are ssh'ing to the router itself. I can't find any other explanation. Please, let me know what happened and vote up if my help has been of any use :-)

Comment: Hey, sorry it took me a while to get back to you. It turns out that the apartment where my friend lives in has its own network. So it's kind of like: the Internet -- Apartment's network -- my friend's home network. The apartment's network was blocking the connection, and when he called the customer service, they told him that he needed to pay 30 bucks per port! So, he unwillingly tried to pay that much and open port 22/tcp but they told him that only ports with numbers larger than 1023 can be opened. That was as far as we went. Thanks for your help! We couldn't have gotten this far without it.

Comment: I will also vote up your answer once I have a reputation of 15 :)

Comment: You can have them map any port number from outside to port 22 inside. Alternatively,  you could have ssh service configured to use a port other than the default 22. Don't worry about voting. I am happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.
Try to use your external ip adres  find your ex.ip adress on http://www.whatismyip.com/.
I've sit for almost  4 weeks to find out not to use my 192.168.x.xxx adress
 but to use the external one 88.67.xx.xxx.
Excuse me for my television english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) to tunnel ssh traffic through HTTP. No need to pay that ridiculous $30.